# How Do I Remove the tiny Outline in my Progress Bar CSS?

Tags: css

I'm created a progress bar and for some reason, it shows a weird outline and I don't know what to change to fix it. Here is a picture below. You can see that tiny spacing and I don't know why it shows there

[image]

Here is a codepen showing the same exact outline issue https://codepen.io/designextras/pen/PoZKJMK

Note: I am using google chrome to view this

html code

```
  <div id="progressBar">
  <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
  </div>
```

css code

```
#progressBar {
width: 20rem;
height: 4rem;
border: 0.2rem solid rgb(18, 93, 255);
margin-top: 2rem;
border-radius: 66px;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 1;
 }

#progressBarFull {
height: 4rem;
background-color: rgb(18, 93, 255);
width: 50%;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line.

```
#progressBarFull {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(18, 93, 255);
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: that didn't do anything, still has the little line

Comment: reduce border-radius upto 20px;

Comment: Yes, I look and giving all suggestions based on codepen results.